# What's the best way to let a user add or remove users in a sharepoint group?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to grant as user access to add/remove user from a particular SharePoint group. What is the best way to do this?
SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a new group 'XXX Group owners'
2. Make 'Site owners' and this user members of 'XXX Group owners'
3. Make 'XXX Group owners' owner of the 'XXX' group

That way the only extra permission you've given that user is to control that group

Comment: Thank you Per Jakobsen. I had done that however the mystery to me is where does the group owner go to add or remove persons. What page? Which area? Thank you!

Comment: where does the group owner go to add or remove persons. What page? Which area?

Comment: Please help per Jakobsen?

Comment: There is no easy navigation, but they can go to `https://TheSharePointSite/_layouts/15/groups.aspx` and click on the group where they are owner.